# Why did Tony Stark and Pepper break up?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, iron-man, captain-america-civil-war

There is a scene in *Captain America: Civil War* where Steve Rogers asks Tony about his relationship with Pepper and Tony Stark says that they are taking a break. So did they break up simply because Pepper couldn't take the fact of him continuing to be Iron Man?

Comment: that is a very plausible thought but I dont rembember if any evidence was ever surfaced that pepper would go as far as t break up with him because of that.

Comment: Out of universe, it's most likely because Gwyneth Paltrow doesn't really want to be in any more MCU films.

Comment: @RogueJedi sources?

Comment: Because he's a schmuck.

Comment: [Because strawberries.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=V1jlUCqZPLY)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## He's "hard to deal with".

In the film, Tony is fairly candid with Steve Rogers as to the reasons for the strain in his relationship with Pepper.  He explains to Steve that:

- The relationship had begun to unravel after the climactic events of *Iron Man 3* in which Pepper had been almost killed.
- His continued use of Iron suits despite Pepper's concerns for his safety had driven a wedge between them.
- The Sokovia incident, which was a product of Tony's recklessness (via Ultron), had worsened his already-strained relations with Pepper.

He then admitted that, on top of these specific obstacles, he is simply **"hard to deal with"**.

Comment: I think he said the fact he kept making suits didn't help too

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn: I took that as a reference to Pepper's desire for Tony to stop placing himself at risk of injury/death by *using* the suits he keeps making, rather than any objection to manufacturing distractions/processes *per se*—perhaps that's what you meant too?  Istr Pepper has raised similar concerns in previous films?

Comment: @eggyal yes meant making for him to be in and use

Comment: Is any of this related to Tony destroying all of his suits at the end of IM3 as proof of his devotion to Pepper, and then promptly building a new suit plus a small army of drones just in time for Avengers 2? I could see Pepper feeling a little miffed by that course of action.